# Android Opengl Point not Drawn

Tags: android, opengl-es

I have two classes to draw Points and Lines. But points are not drawn on screen.
I am getting an error as below,

> distrib/android-emugl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glGetUniformLocation:1512
>   error 0x501

Point class not working well. In my render class I have arraylist to hold point
line objects and code iterates through arrrays to draw these primitives.

my point class

```
private FloatBuffer VertexBuffer;

private final String VertexShaderCode =
        // This matrix member variable provides a hook to manipulate
        // the coordinates of the objects that use this vertex shader
        "uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;" +
                "attribute vec3 vPosition;" +
                "void main() {" +
                // the matrix must be included as a modifier of gl_Position
                "  gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * vec4(vPosition,1.0f);" +
                "gl_PointSize = 30.0;" +
                "}";

private final String FragmentShaderCode =
        "precision mediump float;" +
                "uniform vec4 vColor;" +
                "void main() {" +
                "  gl_FragColor = vColor;" +
                "}";

protected static int GlProgram;
protected int PositionHandle;
protected int ColorHandle;
protected int MVPMatrixHandle;

// number of coordinates per vertex in this array
static final int COORDS_PER_VERTEX = 3;
static float PointCoords[] = {
        0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
};

private final int VertexCount = PointCoords.length / COORDS_PER_VERTEX;
private final int VertexStride = COORDS_PER_VERTEX * 4; // 4 bytes per vertex

// Set color with red, green, blue and alpha (opacity) values
float color[] = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f };

public Point() {
    // initialize vertex byte buffer for shape coordinates
    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(
            // (number of coordinate values * 4 bytes per float)
            PointCoords.length * 4);
    // use the device hardware's native byte order
    bb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());

    // create a floating point buffer from the ByteBuffer
    VertexBuffer = bb.asFloatBuffer();
    // add the coordinates to the FloatBuffer
    VertexBuffer.put(PointCoords);
    // set the buffer to read the first coordinate
    VertexBuffer.position(0);

    int vertexShader = GLRender.loadShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER, VertexShaderCode);
    int fragmentShader = GLRender.loadShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, FragmentShaderCode);

    GlProgram = GLES20.glCreateProgram();             // create empty OpenGL ES Program
    GLES20.glAttachShader(GlProgram, vertexShader);   // add the vertex shader to program
    GLES20.glAttachShader(GlProgram, fragmentShader); // add the fragment shader to program
    GLES20.glLinkProgram(GlProgram);                  // creates OpenGL ES program executables
}

public void SetPointVerts(float v0, float v1, float v2) {
    PointCoords[0] = v0;
    PointCoords[1] = v1;
    PointCoords[2] = v2;

    VertexBuffer.put(PointCoords);
    // set the buffer to read the first coordinate
    VertexBuffer.position(0);
}

public void SetPointColor(float red, float green, float blue, float alpha) {
    color[0] = red;
    color[1] = green;
    color[2] = blue;
    color[3] = alpha;
}

public void draw(float[] mvpMatrix) {
    // Add program to OpenGL ES environment
    GLES20.glUseProgram(GlProgram);

    // get handle to vertex shader's vPosition member
    PositionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(GlProgram, "vPosition");

    // Enable a handle to the triangle vertices
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(PositionHandle);

    // Prepare the triangle coordinate data
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(PositionHandle, COORDS_PER_VERTEX,
            GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
            VertexStride, VertexBuffer);

    // get handle to fragment shader's vColor member
    ColorHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(GlProgram, "vColor");

    // Set color for drawing the triangle
    GLES20.glUniform4fv(ColorHandle, 1, color, 0);

    // get handle to shape's transformation matrix
    MVPMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(GlProgram, "uMVPMatrix");
    //GLRender.checkGlError("glGetUniformLocation");

    // Apply the projection and view transformation
    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(MVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, mvpMatrix, 0);
    //GLRender.checkGlError("glUniformMatrix4fv");


    // Draw the triangle
    GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_POINTS, 0, VertexCount);

    // Disable vertex array
    GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(PositionHandle);
}
```

09-08 10:57:28.308 29430-29494/com.timescale.lenovo.sds I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
09-08 10:57:28.330 29430-29494/com.timescale.lenovo.sds D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
09-08 10:57:28.343 29430-29494/com.timescale.lenovo.sds W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
09-08 10:57:28.343 29430-29494/com.timescale.lenovo.sds W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xae54a080, error=EGL_SUCCESS
09-08 10:57:28.498 29430-29438/com.timescale.lenovo.sds W/art: Suspending all threads took: 9.892ms
09-08 10:57:38.010 29430-29494/com.timescale.lenovo.sds W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
09-08 10:57:38.011 29430-29494/com.timescale.lenovo.sds W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa30640a0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
09-08 10:57:39.324 29430-29430/com.timescale.lenovo.sds E/libEGL: call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)
09-08 10:57:39.392 29430-29493/com.timescale.lenovo.sds E/emuglGLESv2_enc: glDrawArrays: no data bound to the command - ignoring
09-08 10:57:39.394 29430-29493/com.timescale.lenovo.sds E/emuglGLESv2_enc: glDrawArrays: no data bound to the command - ignoring

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring vPosition attribute as vec4 (homogeneous coords) yet in Java code you are uploading vec3 vertices via glVertexAttribPointer (COORDS_PER_VERTEX const is set to 3). Either change you geometry definition or your shader code to accept 3 element vectors:

```
private final String VertexShaderCode =
        // This matrix member variable provides a hook to manipulate
        // the coordinates of the objects that use this vertex shader
        "uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;" +
        "attribute vec3 vPosition;" +
        "void main() {" +
         // the matrix must be included as a modifier of gl_Position
         "  gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * vec4(vPosition, 1.0);" +
         "  gl_PointSize = 30.0;" +
         "}";
```

Side note, since you vertices contains only position data you can simply set stride to 0 (elements are tightly packed)

Comment: I have tried your comments but I am stil getting same error. While debuging error occurs in line below. PositionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(GlProgram, "vPosition");

Comment: 0x501 is GL_ERROR_INVALID_VALUE but since you are not checking it after every call it may actually be caused by some other call, add some additional debugs to pinpoint your issue.

Comment: I have add debug after your sugestion as shown above

Comment: Passing only 3 components to an attribute that has 4 components in the shader code is perfectly valid, and well defined. The w component of the vector will implicitly be set to 1.

Comment: @RetoKoradi You are correct, I wasn't aware of this.

Comment: @utta You've just pasted some generic Android system logs, not additional logs after checking GL calls.

Comment: please check my other post in which I have provided my some major coding http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39410064/real-device-test-opengl-es-2